# what are sql server index disable advantages?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Most people use "index disable" for bulk import / update operations.

There are 2 approches used. Like these:

1- drop index -> bulk import/update operations -> create index

2- disable index -> bulk import/update operations -> rebuild index

What are the superiorities of second one?

Comment: You don't need to keep the corresponding DDL somewhere.

Comment: `ALTER INDEX ALL ON t DISABLE/REBUILD`. Now compare that to the syntax for dropping and creating specific indexes and the benefits should be clear. Even if you don't want to disable *all* indexes, merely having to name them is far simpler.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Suppose we have a disabled index, a clustered index. This leads to other problems. It also disables foreign keys, for example. It also disables other indexes. But if I do drop and create a clustered index, I do not try to rebuild the other indexes, do not try to enable foreign keys.

Comment: Hence "even if you don't want to disable all indexes..." I'm merely pointing out that `ALTER INDEX ALL` exists, of course you wouldn't always use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the second solution you basically don't need to keep the exact DDL for the index, that might be quite complicated.

The only detail you need is an index name to rebuild, which is both easier and less error prone.

References:

- [`ALTER INDEX` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql)